# Vertical divs in a parent with max-height

Tags: html, css, sass

So I'm trying to make a box/div with a max-height that contains 2 vertical scrollable lists of items that adjusts their heights depending on the amount of the items while still fitting in the parents' max-height. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9USa.png). And if both of them have overflowing items I want both lists to have 50% height. [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xlQ8.png). Sorry if this sounds a little cryptic and hard to understand, having a hard time trying to describe it.

This is what I currently have.

HTML:

```
<div class="list-box">
   <div class="list-1">
      <ul>
         <li>item</li>
         <li>item</li>
         <li>item</li>
         <li>item</li>
         <li>item</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="list-2">
      <ul>
         <li>item</li>
         <li>item</li>
         <li>item</li>
         <li>item</li>
         <li>item</li>
         <li>item</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
.list-box {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   max-height: calc(100vh - 15rem);
   
   .list-1,
   .list-2 { 
      height: auto;
      overflow-y: auto;
   }
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried? [A minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) helps other get started answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will fix your issue.
**HTML**

```html
<div class="parent-wrap">
    <div class="child-wrap"></div>
    <div class="child-wrap"></div>
<div>
```

**CSS**

```css
 .parent-wrap {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    height:600px;
    padding: 3px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    
  }
  
  .child-wrap {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  
  .child-wrap:nth-child(1) {
     max-height: 50%; 
  }
  
  .child-wrap:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 1; 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's really close to what I'm trying to achieve but is there a way for one of the child-wraps to fully expand to the parents' height as well if the other one is smaller rather than having the max-height 50%.

Comment: I have updated the CSS. now check.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't need to flex.

```css
/*CSS:*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list-box {
  height: 500px;
  border: solid green;
}

.list-1,
.list-2 {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 50%;
}

.list-1 {
  border: solid red;
}

.list-2 {
  border: solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<div class="list-box">
  <div class="list-1">
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-2">
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```